# Book about a kid who gets sucked into his computer game

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to rediscover a book I read long ago.  The only things I can remember about this book are:

- That this kid is playing the video game he is playing it when he should have been doing his homework.
- In the middle of the night he either falls asleep or get sucked into the video game because there's a hypnotic picture thing going on on his computer screen.
- His character in the game is a ghoul — the type that feasts on the bodies of dead monsters and people — which gives him extraordinary strength and stuff like that (basically he's a zombie in this game).
- He is now in the world of the game, which is a dungeon with companions.  The plot of the game is to defeat a necromancer (or something like that) because these people are evil wizards that have summoned him (or something like that) into the game (... I mean in the movie or I mean in the book).  He must defeat the evil magician in order to get home.
- He has a friend who was supposed to be female but is male ... his name was Chubby? ... he finds his friend outside of the dungeon and discovers they were friends in real-life.
- His friend finds out that the clothes are too small for him because they are literally choking the life out of him.
- His friend goes on to defeat a Horseman (or a plague caused by the Horseman) that I believe was hurting a Village for a while.
- And all the while they are doing this, it is still a video game that he has been sucked into.  He finds one guy who is playing it as an avatar, yet he is able to control it through the game people.  There are also others who have been sucked into the game, including a girl that has no memory of it being a video game and just thinks of it as real life.  She is a Slave (it's similar to World of Warcraft).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: Similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141849/y-a-1980s-book-about-kids-pulled-into-computer-game?rq=1

Comment: could be [User Unfriendly](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/372808.User_Unfriendly), or [Keeper of the Kingdom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/632638.Keeper_of_the_Kingdom).  It would help to know approximately when you read the book.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for the book *[Discordia: The Eleventh Dimension](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3678729-discordia)* by Dena Salmon.

The main characters name is 'Lance', a level 19 zombie sorcerer within the video game. His online friend 'MrsKeller', a level 23 hobgoblin brigand within the game who turns out to be a "Mr", meets Lance as the zombie sorcerer post "getting sucked into the game". They go to find out that 'TheGreatOne' is responsible for teleporting Lance and his friend (among others) into the actual land of Discordia. In order to leave, they must complete high level quests that will determine the fate of Discordia, Lance, and his friend, 'Mrskeller'.

Comment: I have no idea if this is accurate, and we're unlikely to hear back from the OP, but kudos on answering a 2+ year old question with relevant details!

Comment: Unfortunately, i believe you're right about OP. Their wonderful description aided me in finding the book id been looking for. Thanks for the kudos!

Comment: My local library has a copy of the book, so I've requested it just for a quick double-check on the other details, but it looks like you're rihgt on this one.

Comment: @Aaron: Stick around for a bit, and you should be getting some bounty.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I appreciate you looking into this further! Its a good read if you're into sci-fy and fantasy books. It might be a much lower reading level than what you may be used to, but a good read nonetheless.

Comment: ^_^ I read a ton of kids books, much to my wife's chagrin.

Comment: Maybe consider giving it a read while you have it!